# Capturar o nome da placa de vídeo atraves da dll NVAPI

Tags: c#, dll

Como importar a DLL "nvapi.dll" para o programa em C#? Não tenho claro como capturar o nome da placa de vídeo:

```
NvAPI_GPU_GetFullName  -  CEEE8E9F
```

Comment: Precisa ser com a NVAPI?

Comment: sim jbueno eu gostaria de aprender pois com o WMI eu já conheço.

Comment: Essa informação você pega com a nvcpl.dll, não é?